# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[2,7,11,15]'

Tags: python, runtime-error

When I run this code in my pc it is ok but when I submit it on leetcode it gives runtime more like above. Error :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[2,7,11,15]'
    if (int(arr[i])+int(arr[j]))==target and int(arr[i])!=int(arr[j]) and cnt<1:
Line 11 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Hoe should I fix this?

```
arr=[]

arr=input()
arr=arr.split()

target=int(input())
cnt=0
for i,num in enumerate(arr):
    for j,num1 in enumerate(arr):

        if (int(arr[i])+int(arr[j]))==target and int(arr[i])!=int(arr[j]) and cnt<1:
            li=[]

            li.append(i)
            li.append(j)
            li=sorted(li)
            print(li)
            cnt=cnt+1;
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: a list like 4 7 9 8 and a integer

Comment: `arr` is `['[2,7,11,15]']` after the split.

Comment: Do you understand what leetcode is inputting when it tests the code? It seems to be different from how you supply the input. You should read the specification more closely.

Comment: As is, we can't help you solve the problem, even approaching it as a homework question, because we cannot see the actual problem you are being expected to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error suggest a conversion fail, probably when you try to cast `arr[...]` to integer.

As you can see on the error, you try to convert `[2,7,11,15]` to int which immediately failed. Your logic was probably wrong on `arr.split`: you assumed the input will be given with whitespaces (aka `2 7 11 15`), while it is being given with commas to separate (`[2, 7, 11, 15]`).

For that exact input, you should use `arr=arr.split(',')` and also remove the '[' and ']' on the beginning & end of the string. You can do this with taking only substring of `arr`.

Fixed line: `arr = arr[1:-1].split(',')`.

This should cover the specific input that cause a problem. Having said that, I'm not sure if it will cover all cases since you did not gave the full assignment. It depends on how you assume input will be given.